# g++ can't find headers but I did include them

Tags: c++, linker, g++, header-files, leveldb

I am starting on c++ and already going wrong ...

I am trying to compile a small test of levelDB :

```
#include <assert.h>
#include "leveldb/db.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  leveldb::DB* db;
  leveldb::Options options;
  options.create_if_missing = true;
  leveldb::Status status = leveldb::DB::Open(options, "/tmp/testdb", &db);
  assert(status.ok());

  return 1;
}
```

Here is the g++ command :

```
g++ -I include/ testLevelDB.cpp
```

Output:

```
/tmp/ccuBnfE7.o: In function `main':
testLevelDB.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `leveldb::Options::Options()'
testLevelDB.cpp:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `leveldb::DB::Open(leveldb::Options const&, std::string const&, leveldb::DB**)'
```

The include folder is the one with the levelDB headers.

Comment: That is an error thrown by the linker, not by the compiler. You forgot to link a library you included.

Comment: @arkascha - you are right; I had already removed my comment since it was irrelevant.

Comment: I am assuming `leveldb` is from http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/ Did you download and install `leveldb` correctly?  You may need to provide the path to the library in your linker command. For that matter - you may need to build the library first, depending on how you downloaded it.

Comment: @Floris yes I actually did forget to build it ... that works better when it is !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the linker to link to the `leveldb` library such as

```
g++ -I include/ testLevelDB.cpp -lleveldb
```

But this won't work if the library is not in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib` for that case assuming the libleveldb.so exists in some path called `$LEVELDB_PATH` you need to do

```
g++ -I include -L $LEVELDB_PATH testLevelDB.cpp -lleveldb
```

`-L` is much like `-I` but it tells the linker where to looks for libraries.

Also since you seem to be new to gcc world, please have a look at [this](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/ref/gcc-intro.html) gcc intro document.

Comment: I got :
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lleveldb

Comment: Thats because the library is not in /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib, updating answer accordingly.

Comment: You might need a -L too to specify a path for where to find the leveldb library. That goes in the link-phase though, where you set the target. The above looks like a compile command.

Comment: @CashCow: `g++` will compile and link, unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: @ismail why is it that if I put the source file after the shared lib I get the same errors but it works vice versa. Like so `testLevelDB.cpp -lleveldb` works but `-lleveldb testLevelDB.cpp` breaks

Comment: @Laser because linking order matters.

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit confusing since order doesn't matter in most Gnu programs

Comment: @Laser linking order is quite important, just read about another interesting bug on Windows, due to linking order (partially): https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3103806

Answer (score 1):

It is a linkage error. Not related to the headers. Did you link with this lib (-l..) ?

Comment: Hu, no. How do I link it ? I specify the folder of the headers ?

Comment: Depends what "leveldb" is.. Is it a library (ends with .so) - use -l..  or if is it a cpp file or .a file - just add them to the gcc input